# what to backup (for partial restore)??

Tags: backup

My site has hacked three times, and as forced by host provider, now there is no option in front of me, except restoring a healthy backup for around 3 weeks ago. (Hacker had created a backdoor in my site, and was using my site for sending mass spam emails, and i couldn't find that backdoor. I could only remove bad files which was uploaded by hacker).

Before restoring that old backup (for 3 weeks ago), what i must to backup - or download- to add posts created during these 3 weeks. I mean, if restore backup of 3 weeks ago, i lose all posts created during this 3 weeks. what must i do to get my site to current state with all posts, pictures, ...

Thanks in advance
(and sorry for bad english)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To backup only posts,pages and related media files for 3 week.

You need to do the following:-

1. Backup Database of website for post/page text.
2. Backup wp-content\uploads folder for media.

Then you can delete all files and restore old files.Once all old files uploaded then you can upload wp-content\uploads folder of current site.

PS: check uploads and folders in it for any backdoor code.

**Edit**

Once restoration is done install [Anti-Malware](https://wordpress.org/plugins/gotmls/) WordPress plugin and scan for any malware files in them.
It is better plugin.

Comment: Thanks. I need subfolders of Uploads folder for current and last month OR all of uploads folder? also, in uploads folder, I should check php files or picture files may be malicous, too. (I faced another qusetion. Do we have wp-xmlrpc.php in wordpress? it sounds a suspicious file!!!)

Comment: You are welcome.Yes,only current and last month sub folder. PHP files should not be in uploads folder. xmlrpc.php is a WordPress core file. wp-xmlrpc.php is not.

Comment: wp-xmlrpc.php may be virus file.

Comment: I uploaded above file to http://speedy.sh/UYkaK/wp-xmlrpc.php

Comment: Yes.it is a malware file.you can delete it.

Comment: I uploaded above file to http://speedy.sh/UYkaK/wp-xmlrpc.php  . I know coding but i'm unfamiliar with PHP syntax. As i see base64_decode function and a pointer to class-wp-optimize.php file which does not belong to wordpress package. It sounds this file has been the main source of hack, for injecting codes, etc. But unfortunately, i can't understand what it does with wp-themes folder. I've already deleted and replaced wp-admin and wp-includes folder, so i'm sure with safety of these folders. what should i do for wp-contents ? (sorry, it sounds i have changed the direction of topic.)

Comment: Since you have deleted these extra files which doesn't belong to WordPress and restored wp-admin and wp-includes folder.So there should not a problem for these. You can also replace theme and plugins folder in wp-contents and scan uploads folder for extra php files.

Comment: check answer again under edit.

Comment: It's very kind of you. I'm gonna test that plugin. How should i replace plugins folder? Removing plugins and installing them again? what about configuration of plugins? any way to keep them?

Comment: I love u, man. Thanks a whole world for introducing this nice plugin. It worked perfectly and found malware code in PHP files. It seems to me that main source of hacking was MyBB forum. I'd not updated my forum for a while (although it has been just some minor fixes in recent updates) and I'm gonna update it soon. Thanks again.